# Swift: addGestureRecognizer not work for stackview children

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, stackview

Codes:

```
for ... {
   let view = CategoryClass.createMyClassView()
   view.myLabel.text = packTitle
   view.twoLabel.text = packText
   view.bgCaategory.layer.cornerRadius = 30

   i = i + 1
   if(i == 1){
      selectPackId = packId!;
      view.imgSelect.image = UIImage(named: "selected")
   } else {
      view.imgSelect.image = UIImage(named: "select")
   }

   view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSendData(sender:))))

   self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
}

@objc func handleSendData(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("H 1")
}
```

If i click on view, nothing print "H 1"

I want if i click on view, get id or another value of view

Comment: Try to set a frame to your UIView : 
`view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)`

Comment: @AnthonyR not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the UIStackView in interface builder, the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property is false by default. This means that the view and all it's child views won't respond to user interaction.

When you create a view in code, this property is `true` be default.

Add:

```
stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

You only have to add this once, in your `viewDidLoad` for example.

Answer (score 4):

If adding `isUserInteractionEnabled` as suggested by Marcel still doesn't work, also make sure that every parent view in the hierarchy has a valid frame (you can check it in `Debug View Hierarchy`).

E.g. it happened to me to add a `UIStackView` into a parent `UIView` but the layout constraints were not correct, so I ended up having the parent `UIView` frame size as 0 (but the UIStackView was still visible).

Answer (score -1):

The reason it doesn’t work is possibly a wrong method signature. The correct signature for recognizer actions is this:

```
recognizerAction(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: Instead of `@objc func handleSendData(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` use this: `@objc func handleSendData(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` and change the call to this: `#selector(handleSendData(_:))`. Not sure, though, if it will solve your problem, but at least this is what a gesture recognizer expects.